# Wifi HotSpot: have you ever seen Safari automatically launched at connexion?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, safari, ios, captive-portal

This is a simple question of usage. Have you ever seen ? or never ?

I'm building a Wifi hotspot for iOSX (iDevices & Mac). And your help is very welcome.

You probably already connected to a hotspot (hostels, restaurants, neighbourhood, etc). This open a popup, generally to ask you to login, or to ask you to accept the *Term Of Service*.

In such a case, have you ever **seen** Safari opening a page once you logged, or once you ve accepted the *Term of service* ? Or have you always launched Safari by yourself after ?

**Brief, seen it when you click a button inside the popup.**

Much thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you design the login page, you might be able to make the submit button open a link in Safari. My highschool used a Ruckers Wireless login and when you accepted the terms and conditions it opened the school's main website. Also many burger kings, starbucks, and the such that offer free wifi open their own sites after you log in.

Comment: Thank you -- are you very very sure it opens Safari ? It is so automatic to launch it right after.

Comment: what about iPhones ? or iPads ?

Comment: What it does is it puts a link in the button so when it's clicked, the link is activated, opening in the default browser. For Mac that can be any browser but for iPhones/iPads I think it will always open in Safari